# How to create a custom table containing data to be rendered using the Views module

Tags: views

I have a module which is pulling in some remote data. this is only temporary as long as page is opened i dnt want to store the data on my drupal site. is there a way i can create a custom data table in order to render my data results using the views module.
i looked into hook_views_data()but it seems this only works with database table in the drupal system

Answer (score 1):

[Data](https://drupal.org/project/data) module helps you model, manage and query related sets of tables. 
The Data module provides

- an API for dynamically allocating tables for single-row records.
- an API for insert/update/delete operations and describing how tables join to each other.
- **automatic views integration.**
- a way to export table definitions to code.

Also next patch in "[Describe and use external database tables using Data](https://drupal.org/node/864184)." allow use external DB tables to show on Views.

Answer (score 1):

Module [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) can be used to query (not update) any MySQL database table.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://www.forenasolutions.org) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The newest 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Here are some variations of the **MySQL database** part in my answer:

1. Using a **SQLite** instead of MySQL database: the Forena samples actually get shipped including a (Tiny) SQLite database. Go check it out in the [demo site](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/samples): the data shown there are data contained in the sampledb, which is in SQLite format.
2. Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

Enough reasons for considering giving Forena a try? While doing so, use it's issue queue for any type of support/docu requests you may have.

Be aware: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.